# Deprecated Tag on Hibernate Annotation

Tags: hibernate, orm

Hibernate newbie here.  I am trying my best to understand Hibernate and ORM in general and I do think I like some of the examples that I have been doing.

I am used to hard-core JDBC alone mapping and I really like what this Hibernate can bring.

But question though, I am at the annotation section now.

```
Configuration config = new AnnotationConfiguration();
config.configure();
```

But when I look up at the Javadocs of Hibernate 3.6 it has a tag of @Deprecated.  All the tutorial that I am following is mentioning about how to configure annotation with these steps.  But it didnt mention about any deprecation.

Am I missing something? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the base class Configuration directly

```
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.configure();
```

you will find in java doc for AnnotationConfiguration:

> Deprecated. All functionality has been moved to Configuration